# UITableViewCell does not reflect changes after dismissing a modally presented ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, segue

I have a UIViewController with a TableView for displaying the 'checklist' items. This ViewController also has a button that trigger the segue to modally present another UIViewController that is for users to add the new checklist items.

All checklist items are stored in CoreData.

The new CoreData entity is created, and stored by the `SecondViewController`. Users can add as much `checklist` items as they want before hitting a button that triggers the dismissal of the `SecondViewController`. Here since this `SecondViewController` is modally presented, I assume that its activity does not have any relation with the `FirstUIViewController` at all.

At the `FirstViewController`, which contains `UITableView`, there is a `NSFetchedResultsController` that performs the fetch request at the CoreData again and feed all the data to `UITableView`. NSFetchedResultsController's delegate is also point to this `FirstUIViewController`.

The problem is that, after the dismissal of `SecondViewController`, the `UITableView` seems to notice the insertion of the new checklist entity, and inserted the new `UITableCell` inside the UITableView. However, weirdly, this newly inserted row doesn't display the proper `cell.textlabel`. Only blank `UITableViewCell` with nothing on the label is presented.

Below is how I configure the `UITableViewCell`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ChecklistCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ChecklistItem *item = [self.fetch_controller objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = item.name;    
}
```

Here is what I have for the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            NSLog(@"*** controllerDidChangeObject - NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert");
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

Forcing the `[self.tableView reloadData]` seems to help. I know this because I added one button to invoke this method, and the cell's label got refreshed and updated accordingly.

Therefore, I tried this as I hope it would get called after the dismissal of `SecondViewController`. However, the method gets called because `Reload Data!` got logged, but somehow the tableView still doesn't show the newly added cell's label properly.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self performFetch];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Reload Data!");
}
```

I wonder what could be wrong here. Somehow the `self.tableView` doesn't get reloaded after the dismissal of the `SecondViewController`. Any suggestions?

## edited

OK, more weird is that I tried `[self.tableView reloadData]` inside `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`. The new tableViewCell still doesn't display its label properly; however, after waiting for 30 seconds, the label just magically pops up! Does this means that my iPhone/iPhone simulator needs time to think much?

Comment: Are you saving the data in the modal view controller?

Comment: Yes, the SecondViewController handles all the saving process. The FirstViewController just fetches and displays the data.

Comment: Did you implement controllerWillChangeContent and call [self.tableView beginUpdates]? You will also need a [self.tableView endUpdates] when implementing controllerDidChangeContent.

Comment: @bbarnhart I did have both of them. The delegate code was a bit long, so I didn't paste all of them here. Guess I need to figure out a way to get notified once all new checklist item get inserted properly by using these delegate methods.

Comment: Remove all the code from viewWillAppear.  None of that is needed. Next, add a NSLog message to each method that will be hit during an insert.  This trace should help you see what is not being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation**

Your core data save takes time. If you are saving the data and then immediately dismiss the modal view controller, you have a race condition on the `performFetch` function. This is why you're seeing that it doesn't work in the `viewWillAppear` function, but it works when you press a button. It will sometimes work in viewDidAppear, but it is not guaranteed. It depends on whether you're using the simulator, and how busy the system is.

**Concrete Suggestion**

Since you are pulling data from core data, I suggest that you use `NSFetchedResultsController` and implement `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`. These were designed specifically for binding coreData to a UITableViewController. It listens for changes and immediately adds, deletes, or updates rows based on those changes.

**UPDATE with Code**

To properly implement `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`, you can simply copy code from this website: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

A few tips:

1. You need to make a slight change to how you implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Create a new method called `configureCell`. It's a well worn pattern so you can find it in many sample code from Apple and other places.
2. Copy the code from the "Typical Use" section of the website above. You don't need to implement "User-Driven Updates". Be sure to set

   `self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;`
3. If you want to check if this code is working properly, you can put in breakPoints or NSLogs into `controllerWillChangeContent` or `controller:didChangeObject`.
4. You don't need to call performFetch ever again after the first time. This code listens for changes and updates appropriately.
5. As I always advise everyone -- I love MagicalRecord -- so use it.

**Configure Cell**

The configureCell:atIndexPath method below is called by the NSFetchedResultsController delegate.

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Product *product = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = product.name;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Product Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

See the delegate implementation code here. See how configureCell is called when an object is updated.

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                    atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Hi Eddie, I did use NSFetchedResultsController an its delegate to take care of the fetching.  Is there a way to check and wait to see if all the data has been inserted properly before calling performFetch again?

Comment: In fact, the delegate method kind of works since it knows that the new data has been inserted and therefore tableview add the new row. However, the cell label was not shown properly, though.

Comment: @Kann if the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate is properly implemented, you do not want to call performFetch ever again after the first time. brb with another comment.

Comment: @Kann, I updated the answer above to include tips on properly implementing the delegate and checking to see if it is working. On your note about the cell label not being shown properly -- You have to make sure that the cell formatting and updating code is in "configureCell". This is how the FetchedResults delegate is updating the cell.

Comment: Hi Eddie, thanks for your tips, but I'm afrai that I might still not quite understand the difference between the need of implementing the new configureCell and ConfigureCellAtInsexPath. I mean, all I did in my method was only assign the label text from the checklist item. :$

Comment: What happened was that there was no delayed in accessing core data if I add the new checklist item within the same view controller. The delegate works and tableview got updated with correct label instantly. However, if the new item got added in the modal view controller, then I need to wait and reload the table. Checklist item only contains NSString value and a integer attribute. This is not a big object, and it should take long to handle the save, I wonder...

Comment: @Kann, I just noticed that you have not fully implemented the delegate in the code you posted above. You did not implement NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert, which is why it would not automagically add a new item. Also it's important to call table beginUpdates and endUpdates. I recommend that you implement the entire code that I posted above.

Comment: Hi Eddie, now I know what's wrong with my code. I'm sorry that I was not explicit about implementing the delegate methods, but I did have all of them in the place. I just didn't paste all of them here since I thought the only relevant part is about `NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert`. After one good sleep, It turned out that there are something wrong with the thread queue that I used to implement MBProgressHUD on the `SecondViewController`. So, you were right about Core Data race that some data took too long time before it gets completely saved into Core Data. Thanks for your help, though. :)